# Register Eureka Client with Eureka Server AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to deploy a eureka server and a eureka client to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm doing this by creating a zip file and adding the jars created by maven along with a procfile. Locally the eureka client registers with the eureka server via this property:

`eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka`

When I was testing out containerizing my microservices I know I had to override localhost with the eureka server service name in docker-compose.yaml. What do I have to change localhost to in order for this to work on Elastic Beanstalk? In the procfile I tried to use the name of the environment but that didn't work:

```
web: java -jar eureka_server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
web_2: java -jar eureka_client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  --eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://my_env_name:8761
```

Also in order for me to switch between the eureka client and server I have to change the PORT variable in Configuration > Software

Comment: did you fine the ans @Maleke Thomas?  I also having same issue